# Open UITableView after Click on Button

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, nsmutablearray

I have a Tabbar - Application and i want to show data (NSString) from a NSMutableArray in an UITextfield or better in an UITableView after a button-click.

how can i init and open and fill the UITabelView?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a basic implementation of a UITableView. The Apple [UITableView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) should cover any questions you have on UITableViews. For your button click, tie the IBAction of the button to call [yourTableView reload]. This forces a load of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Are your tableView and textField in the same tab where your button is?

Say you have `stringArray` which is holding all the NSString Objects.

then you can set

```
textField.text = [stringArray objectAtIndex:indexYouWant];
```

If you want to add the whole array to tableView, you will need to use that stringArray and implement tableView Methods.

But still I am not clear with your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an overly broad question. Why not look at some example code and try to figure it out? If you get stuck, come back and post a question and some code showing where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

***You need to know the Life Cycle of UIViewController and its UIView***

Concentrate on the methods that are responsible for the life cycle of the UIViewControllera:

```
Creature
Init
initWithNibName:

Creating view
(BOOL) isViewLoaded
LoadView
viewDidLoad
(UIView *) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
(UIView *) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder

Processing state change view
viewDidLoad
ViewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
ViewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
ViewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated
ViewDidDisappear: (BOOL) animated
ViewDidUnload

Processing memory warning
DidReceiveMemoryWarning

Destruction
ViewDidUnload
was given
```

***Proceeding from this in one of the initialization methods after clicking on the button, you must fill out the table and call after the reloaddata***